# Binary search in MIPS assembly not working

Tags: assembly, mips, binary-search

I want to search for a number in the data segment and print out where it’s saved. It works for all numbers except the 1 and the 10000, but I don’t know why, also it prints out the wrong “location”…

Here is the code:

```mips
### Binary search ############################################################
.text
binsearch:
##############################################################################
# $a0 - Number n
# $a1 - Lower bound lo
# $a2 - Upper bound hi
# $v0 - Position where n is found, -1 if not found
##############################################################################

addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 0($sp)
bge $a1, $a2, binsearch_not_found

sub $t0, $a2, $a1
srl $t0, $t0, 2
add $t1, $a1, $t0
sll $t2, $t1, 2
lw $t3, list($t2)
beq $t3, $a0, binsearch_found
blt $t3, $a0, binsearch_upper_half

binsearch_lower_half:
#####################
subi $a2, $t1, 1
jal binsearch
j binsearch_return

binsearch_upper_half:
#####################
addi $a1, $t1, 1
jal binsearch
j binsearch_return

binsearch_found:
################
move $v0, $t2
j binsearch_return

binsearch_not_found:
####################
li $v0, -1

binsearch_return:
#################
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra

### Main #####################################################################
.globl main
main:
##############################################################################

li $v0, 4
la $a0, input
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $a0, $v0

move $a1, $zero
lw $a2, length
subi $a2, $a2, 1
jal binsearch

li $t0, -1
beq $v0, $t0, not_found

found:
######
mul $t0, $v0, 4
lw $a0, list($t0)
li $v0, 1
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, success
syscall
j repeat

not_found:
##########
li $v0, 4
la $a0, failure
syscall

repeat:
#######
li $v0, 4
la $a0, continue
syscall

# Read characters
li $v0, 12
syscall
move $t0, $v0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

# End when 'y'
bne $t0, 'y', main

li $v0, 10
syscall

### Data #####################################################################
.data
##############################################################################

input:    .asciiz "Which number? "
continue: .asciiz "Abort? (y/n) "
failure:  .asciiz "Not found\n"
success:  .asciiz " found\n"
newline:  .asciiz "\n"

length:   .word 100
list:     .word    1,    4,    9,   16,   25,   36,   49,   64,   81,   100,
          .word  121,  144,  169,  196,  225,  256,  289,  324,  361,   400,
          .word  441,  484,  529,  576,  625,  676,  729,  784,  841,   900,
          .word  961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521,  1600,
          .word 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401,  2500,
          .word 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364, 3481,  3600,
          .word 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761,  4900,
          .word 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241,  6400,
          .word 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921,  8100,
          .word 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, feel free to accept and/or upvote it. Otherwise if you need more explanation or guidance, comment on where I should expand.

Answer (score 0):

## Errors found

1. Line 13: `bge $a1, $a2, binsearch_not_found`
   There should be `bgt` because when `$a1 == $a2`, the number `$a0` has been found. If you wanted to interpret `$a2` as strict upper bound, the `subi $a2, $a2, 1` before `binsearch` call in `main` is odd.
2. Line 16: `srl $t0, $t0, 2`
   There should be `1` instead of `2`. You want to divide `$t0` by 2, not by 4.
3. Line 37: `move $v0, $t2`
   There should be `$t1` instead of `$t2`. The `binsearch` should return index into the array, not offset in bytes. If you want to return offset, you should not multiply the return value of `binsearch` by 4 in `main` at line 73 (`mul $t0, $v0, 4`).

## Other observations and thoughts

- There is another way to compute the index of the middle of currently examined interval. Instead of `mid = (hi - lo) / 2 + lo`, you can use `mid = (hi + lo) / 2`. This saves an instruction and overflow is not an issue in your case.
- You use more registers than required in `binsearch`. I managed to use only `$t0` for index and `$t1` for offset from `list` and then the value from that offset. Don’t know how that affects performance, though. (Beware, changing this is error-prone. Be sure to think about where you use the registers’ values and change all of the references at the same time.)
- You print just the number that you found. Printing also the index could be helpful.

## MARS

To debug your code, I used [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/index.htm) simulator of MIPS (from Missouri State University, [nice description](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/mips/Mars/Mars.xhtml) on Gary Shute’s site, University of Minnesota Duluth). I needed to add `j main` before the `binsearch` label, otherwise `binsearch` was executed instead of `main` and that quickly led to a crash.

I turned [delayed branching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot) off in MARS, otherwise a `nop` instruction has to be added after jumps and branches in order not to execute something that should not be executed. I was taught that MIPS has a delay slot, but you seem to not take it into account. I let it be, because you probably know better if your architecture does or does not have a delay slot, and moreover I’m not an assembler programming pro and don’t know the intricacies of programming with delay slot.